# Android app auto destroyed after 75 seconds

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing app, which works as kind of launching hub for other applications. Thing is, my application is always destroyed by system after about 75 seconds after any other external activity is launched from it and stays active.

For instance I am launching browser, or any activity with chooser in it. Then waiting for 75 seconds and back button will take me to Home. With chooser activity I even may see my application exits in background.

How do I avoid this, what may be the reason? My guess is I should have some sort of affinity with launched activities, but I may be wrong.

Here is how I describe my activities. The app is called Speaktoit Assistant on the market you can test it.

```
<activity 
android:name="com.speaktoit.assistant.main.MainActivity" 
android:theme="@style/Theme.DoNotDim"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
android:launchMode="singleTop">     
</activity>

<activity 
android:name="com.speaktoit.assistant.SplashActivity"
android:label="Assistant" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" 
android:noHistory="true"
android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

UPDATE:
Ok, Looks like system halts my app and returns it to initial launcher activity and since SplashActivity is finishOnTaskLaunch="true", then it just exists. Question is how make android to return to MainActivity instead ...

UPDATE 2:
Ok, I have found killTask buried in the code. Problem solved :).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing singletop launchmode?

Comment: Yes I have doublechecked, singleTop removal is not affecting this.